# Ng-repeat not updating with array changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs

I have looked over this issue for many hours and read many other questions that seem entirely the same and I have tried every one of their solutions, but none seem to work.

I have an array of objects (`instructionObj.instructions`) and those objects get repeated with `ng-repeat` and their template is a directive.

```
<div instruction-directive ng-repeat="i in instructionsObj.instructions"> </div>
```

I then allow the items to be sorted using Jquery UI sortable.

```
var first, second;
$( ".sort" ).sortable({
  axis: "y",
  start: function( event, ui ) {
      first = ui.item.index();
  },
  stop: function( event, ui ) {
      second = ui.item.index();
      console.log(first + " " + second);
      rearrange(first, second);
      $scope.$apply();
  }
});
```

I then access the start and end index of the object being moved and rearrange the array accordingly:

```
function rearrange(f, s){
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.instructionsObj.instructions.splice(s, 0,
            $scope.instructionsObj.instructions.splice(f, 1)[0]);
        $scope.$apply();
    });
}
```

All of this works great most of the time. The one scenario I have found a failure is when rearranging the objects as such (one column is the current position of all objects displayed on the screen):

a | b | c | d | a

b | c | d | c | b

c | d | b | b | d

d | a | a | a | c

The last step should be a, d, c, b. But it changes to a, b, d, c.

[image: wrong configuration]

**However**, when I go back to my previous view and come back the correct configuration is displayed, all is well. As you can see I have tried `$timeout` and `$apply()` and many other things, but none seem to work.

I know this is a DOM updating issue because I can log the array and see that it is different (correct) from what the DOM shows (incorrect). Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

I am even using `<pre ng-bind="instructionsObj.instructions|json</pre>` to show the exact layout of the array and it is always correct. My mind is blown.

Comment: Can you provide a plunkr or fiddle or a Stackoverflow snippet?

Comment: There is just so much code it would be difficult, that is why I only provided what really affects this. I have provided and Ionic View link so anyone can download the app and test it.

Comment: you don't have to put all the code in the plunkr, just a [mcve]

Comment: Better said than done. I would have to include the controllers, directives, app.js, css, index.html. That way it works just as I see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately I have found a solution, even though I do not understand why the problem was happening anyway.

In this JS:

```
sortableEle = $('.sort').sortable({
    start: $scope.dragStart,
    update: $scope.dragEnd
});

$scope.dragStart = function(e, ui) {
    ui.item.data('start', ui.item.index());
}
$scope.dragEnd = function(e, ui) {
    var start = ui.item.data('start'),
        end = ui.item.index();

    $scope.instructionsObj.instructions.splice(end, 0,
        $scope.instructionsObj.instructions.splice(start, 1)[0]);
    currentRecipe.setInstructions($scope.instructionsObj.instructions);
    $scope.$apply();
    sortableEle.refresh();
}
```

I needed to call `$scope.$apply()` **as well** as `sortableEle.refresh()` after altering the array.

Again, I do not understand why it would mess up 10% of the time, but that fixed it.

FYI: I changed up the sortable function a little, but it does the same exact thing as before.

Comment: If you are changing `$scope` values outside of Angular lifecycle (like you are, from jQuery sortable callback), you need to manually call `$scope.$apply` to notify all the watchers in that particular `$scope` that there is something changed.

Comment: I was already calling `$apply()`. Wasn't calling the sortable refresh

Comment: Just an FYI when using $apply you should use the callback function syntax where possible. Should your code to be 'applied' throw an exception angular will be non the wiser and not be caught In any angular error handling you may have. (most prominent in promise chains with catch)